# I need to align an image, text on a header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align both image and text on the center of the header, one displayed left, other displayed right. Although I can't get the text centered.

```css
header{
    height: 7em;
    background-color: gray;
}
header h1{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}
header img{
    height: 7em;
    width: 12em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <img src="img/filmes.png" alt="logo"/>
        <h1>Sua Locadora Virtual!</h1>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use line-height:

```css
header{
    height: 7em;
    background-color: gray;
}
header h1{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    line-height: 2em;
}
header img{
    height: 7em;
    width: 12em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <img src="img/filmes.png" alt="logo"/>
        <h1>Sua Locadora Virtual!</h1>
    </header>
```

Comment: Thank you first of all.
Will this work in different screens size ?

Comment: did you try? should do.

Comment: worked on my screen, i had to reajust since i've changed the size of the text. I'm just worried about if it'll render the same in bigger or smaller screens. Thank you once again

Comment: You can check for different resolutions on browser pressing ctrl+= or ctrl+-

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like that:

```
img {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px; /* This should be the half of your img with */
  position: absolute;
}
```

By the way, not the best to integrate the `rel` tag into your header. You should move it to your `head`. But it's not very clear what you really want to achieve?